# How to upgrade ESX 6.7 to 7.0.3 with vCenter's Lifecycle Manager without importing an ISO?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have upgraded vCenter from 6.7 to 7.0.3 (u3e) and next I want to upgrade ESX to 7.0.3. From vCenter's `Lifecycle Manager > Updates` I can see 7.0.3 builds listed but I did not find how I can make a Baseline from here.

[image]

For example, I select the 70u3e build and click `ADD/REMOVE BASELINES` and it'll pop up the following page. Then I click OK but nothing happens.

[image]

So how can I upgrade ESX to builds listed under the `Updates` page?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a Patch Baseline first, then you can add Updates to it.

Go to Baselines and click on `New` -> `Baseline`.

[image]

Select `Patch` as the content type.

[image]

You can add patches here directly, or you can just leave everything empty and click next until it is saved.

Afterwards, when you are in the `Updates` section and click on `Add/Remove Baselines` the patch baseline you created will be available:

[image]

Comment: then what's the `Updates` page used for?

Comment: I played a little with the options, turns out you can actually add Updates to the baseline here. See the updated answer.

Comment: does a Patch baseline support upgrade from 6.7 to 7.0.3? based on my understanding a 7.0 Patch baseline can only patch 7.0 ESX server.

Comment: so the button "ADD/REMOVE BASELINES" actually means "Add to or remove from **existing** baselines". confusing.

Comment: `based on my understanding a 7.0 Patch baseline can only patch 7.0 ESX server` - that's my understanding as well. What means we are back at my original answer: You can only do an upgrade via isos.

Answer (score 0):

Import ESX7 ISO in "Imported ISOs"
Create a baseline - content upgrade - select uploaded iso
attach baseline to host and remediate